# php Dynamic page

Tags: php, url, dynamic

I'm not sure if the title here is appropriate and my explanation might be just as bad but here it goes... I am using the following code to generate web pages:

source: [Dynamic inclusion in PHP](http://inobscuro.com/tutorials/read/16/)

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id']; 

$display = $_GET['display'];
    $displays = array('page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5&amp;id=$id');

if (!empty($display)) {
        if(in_array($display,$displays)) {
            $display .= '.php';
            include($display);
        }
        else {
        echo 'Page not found. Return to
        <a href="index.php">Index</a>';
        }
    }
    else { //show html

?>
```

a typical page:

**www.website.com/dir/index.php?display=page4**

My problem is this: I want to add a page to the array of allowed pages that has a dynamic value. You can see my attempt at this in the code above where i added: 'page5&id=$id'

However when i go to this page:

**www.website.com/dir/index.php?display=page5&id=2**

I get the error message "Page not found. Return to Index". 
(The table row id with value of 2 does exist in the database.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better handle the display and ID values separately. For example like this:

```
<?php

$display = $_GET['display'];
$displays = array('page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5');

if (!empty($display)) {
        if(in_array($display,$displays)) {
            $display .= '.php';
            include($display);
        }
        else {
        echo 'Page not found. Return to
        <a href="index.php">Index</a>';
        }
    }
    else { //show html

?>
```

and in display5.php:

```
 <?php

 // some other initializations

 $id = $_GET['id'];
 if($id == 2) { // make some special actions for id = 2

 // show more html
 ?>
```

Comment: But if the value of id is not passed in the url how can we use $_GET['id']; ? also the value "2" I used as just an arbitrary example to represent a value determined by user navigation.

Comment: If your request goes to `www.website.com/dir/index.php?display=page5&id=2`, as you wrote, the two available $_GET variables will be `$_GET['display']` and `$_GET['id']`. So the ID will be passed inside your snippet. Every file, that gets included there, can also access the $_GET variables, so the `display5.php` can access it. The `if($id == 2) {` was just an example of me for showing off how to deal with the ID. You could do some database SELECT statements here instead, e.g.

Comment: Ok I understand. But now, for whatever reason when I try what you explained it doesnt work even though with the url as in the example i cant even $id = $_GET['id'];
  echo $id;

Comment: Ack. There was a typo. It works now thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just like you will receive a value in `$_GET['display']`, you will receive *another* in `$_GET['id']` with a value of `2`!

PHP separates them from the query string. When you use `in_array()`, you'll check whether `page5` is in `$displays`, as you can see from your code, it's not.

I suggest you use `var_dump($_GET);` and then look at the source of the produced HTML to see how GET parameters are being handled.

Answer (score 1):

Thats why in `$_GET["display"]` stands only "page5" and in `$_GET["id"]` the 2. You can check the ID in the page5.php.

For example in page5:

```
<? if (empty($_GET["id"]) || !is_numeric($_GET["id"])) { die("ID isn't a number!"); } ?>
```